# How to force text outside of a div to the next line?

Tags: html, css, phpbb, bbcode

Working on a dev tracker custom PHPBB BBCode but I am having issues with the text displaying next to the module instead of under it.

EX: http://www.survivaloperations.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4&p=5#p5
in 2nd post.

I want to make the text to the right of it default under it. I have tried 
`display: block
clear: both;
adding a div surrounding the entire module with a width of 100%`

but none seem to work.

Here is the CSS:

```
.tracker_contain {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
        clear: both;
}

#tracker_wrap {
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    width: 515px;
    font-family:"Tahoma", Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.tracker_top {
    padding: 8px 0 0 60px;
    background: url('http://www.survivaloperations.net/dev/images/tracker_top.png') no-repeat top;
    width: 455px;
    height: 22px;
    color: #525252;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}
.tracker_top a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cb00cb;
}
.tracker_top a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.tracker_body {
    padding: 10px 11px 10px 11px;
    background: url('http://www.survivaloperations.net/dev/images/tracker_bg.jpg') no-repeat top;
    width: 493px;
    color: #cb00cb;
    float: left;
}
.tracker_bottom {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 11px 0 0;
    background: url('http://www.survivaloperations.net/dev/images/tracker_bottom.png') no-repeat bottom;
    width: 504px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #575757;
    float: left;
}
.tracker_bottom a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
        color: #575757;
}
.tracker_bottom a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="tracker_contain">
<div id="tracker_wrap">
<div class="tracker_top">Originally Posted By <a href="{URL}" alt="{URL}">{TEXT}</a></div>
<div class="tracker_body">
{TEXT}
</div>
<div class="tracker_bottom"><a href={URL}" alt="Read Post" target="_Blank">Original Post</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Add `clear:both` to the element just after `tracker_wrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS contains

```
float: left
```

for top, body and bottom. You have to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks! Never even crossed my mind of all the things I tried!